# Rendering HTML properly including math tags

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5

When a user designs something in CKEditor5, I save data in the database as a string. Sample string from database record:

```
<p>What is the result of following?</p><p><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><msqrt><mn>16</mn></msqrt><mo>&nbsp;</mo><mo>+</mo><mo>&nbsp;</mo><mfrac><mn>3</mn><mn>9</mn></mfrac><mo>&nbsp;</mo><mo>=</mo><mo>&nbsp;</mo><mo>?</mo></math></p>
```

My question is about rendering html. I could parse the whole html string using the `'html-react-parser'` package perfectly if it doesn't include `<math/>` tags. It did not parse `<math/>` tags and people suggested the `'react-mathjax-preview'` package.

But when I parsed the whole html string with that, it parsed perfectly but then other html tags created on CKEditor5 looked like plain text. So I decided to convert the string to html with "DomParser()" and then loop in its "childNodes" searching if it has a math tag. Then I parsed each one separately with (`parse()` or `<MathJax/>`)

```
import MathJax from 'react-mathjax-preview';
const MathjaxParser = ({ mString }) => {    
   return <MathJax id="math-preview" math={mString} />;
};
export default MathjaxParser;
```

.

```
import React from 'react';
import parse from 'html-react-parser';
import MathJax from 'app/components/MathjaxParser';

const Parser = ({ mString }) => {
    const iparser = new DOMParser();
    const parsedHtml = iparser.parseFromString(mString, 'text/html');
    const itemsArray = [];
    if (!parsedHtml || !parsedHtml.body) return null;

    parsedHtml.body.childNodes.forEach(item => {
        let type = 'normal';
        if (!item.outerHTML) return;
        if (item.outerHTML.includes('xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML')) {
            type = 'math';
        }
        itemsArray.push({ type, html: item.outerHTML });
    });

    return (
        <div className="cursor-pointer">
            {itemsArray.map((item, index) =>
                item.type === 'math' ? (
                    <MathJax key={index} mString={item.html} />
                ) : (
                    <div key={index}>{parse(item.html)}</div>
                )
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Parser;
```

In anywhere of the project, I render it like:

```
import Parser from 'app/components/Parser';

..........
return ( <Parser mString={stringHTML} /> );
```

But I think it is a workaround and I would like to ask what is the correct way you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

react-mathjax-preview VERSION - 2.1.3 will resolve this issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).